# How to click a button multilple times with the same element id in the same page

Tags: jquery, html, protractor

giving an error as

- Failed: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.70)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=78.0.3904.11 (eaaae9de6b8999773fa33f92ce1e1bbe294437cf-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#86}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

Comment: You need to explain better what are you asking and format your code then !

Comment: Write a function and click on button there again

Comment: Why do you want to click it multiple times? Is it disabled(not clickable) when opening the page?

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can try. First, I don't think `.click()` is an option on `ElementArrayFinder` objects. That's what you get when you use `element.all()`. You need to get a specific button out of the list to click on. You can use `.first()`, `.last()`, or `.get(index)` to accomplish this. First and last are pretty self explanatory. Lets say you have 4 of these buttons and you want to click on the third one, it would be:

```
element.all(by.id('next')).get(2).click();
```

I understand from your comments that you have a next button on multiple pages. If there is only one button on each page, you can most likely get away with just using `element(by.id('next'))` instead of `element.all()`. Unless all of those other next buttons are still present in the DOM when you advance to a new page you shouldn't need to use `element.all()`.

Second option is to add a function that uses `ExpectedCondition.elementToBeClickable()` and wait for the button to be clickable before you try to click on it.

```
public EC = ExpectedConditions;

public async waitForElementToBeClickable(element: ElementFinder): Promise<void> {
  await browser.wait(this.EC.elementToBeClickable(element), this.wait);
}
```

Wherever you want to click on the button you would just do it like this:

```
const nextButtons = element.all(by.id('next'));

await waitForElementToBeClickable(nextButtons.first());
await nextButtons.first().click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question "How to click a button multilple times with the same element id in the same page"

```
let nextButton = element(by.id("next"));

await nextButton.click();
await nextButton.click();
await nextButton.click();
```

But this is not your problem, and I don't know why you'd want to click it multiple times if you can't click it even once, getting the above error...

The reason for that is either

- your button is not clickable (greyed out) even for the real user
- or you should use `browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", nextButton.getWebElement());` which will click it regardless of its clickability

However, per your comments it's still not what you looking for... What you're looking for, per my understanding, is if the same button is present in multiple pages how do you click it. answer to this is define it once in the beginning and then click it anywhere in the application, as long as the locator persists

so instead of guessing it would be nice if you analyze what your problem is and let us know, so we can help you